# How to construct a serde struct with this type of JSON format?

Tags: rust, serde, serde-json

I'm trying to construct a JSON in rust using serde using structs.

```
{
  "parent": { "database_id": "123" },
  "properties": {
      "title": {
        "title": [
          {
            "text": {
              "content": "Yurts in Big Sur, 123"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
}
```

There's a lot of nested structures. Should I create a struct for each nest? In the case of the two "title" properties. How do I handle that?

I tried to create a struct for each nest.

Here's how it looks like

```rust
#[derive(Serialize)]
struct DBRow {
    parent: Parent,
    properties: Properties,
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Parent {
    database_id: String
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Properties {
    title: PropTitle
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct PropTitle {
    title: Vec<Text>
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Text {
    content: String
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct CreateUser {
    username: String,
}
```

Comment: Can you add what you have attempted?

Comment: @pigeonhands Hi i edited my post with the attempted structs

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the dezeralization for the `text` field

```
"text": {
    "content": "Yurts in Big Sur, 123"
}
```

Instead of having a `Vec<Text>` in `PropTitle`, you need another struct in between that has the `text` field.

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct PropTitle {
    title: Vec<TextEntry>,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct TextEntry {
    text: Text,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct Text {
    content: String,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, yes if you want to stick with using `derive`, you have little choice besides defining a rust struct for each level and "type" of structure in your JSON. I only have a few mitigating points:

- You could abbreviate the `title` thing a bit by having a `#[derive(Serialize)] struct Titled<T> { title: T }` and then using it as `struct DBRow { properties: Titled<Titled<Vec<Text>>>, … }`. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0008e51fe4cfd3c9c438d9d82c01ad5d). But I doubt it's of much use because:
- You probably have more than one property, so I suspect you'll end up with something like `struct DBRow { properties: HashMap<String, Property>, … }` and  `#[derive(Serialize)] #[serde(rename_all = "snake_case"))] enum Property { Title (Vec<Text>) }` anyway.
- If you don't like working with the deeply nested set of structs in your rust code, you can make serde automatically convert structs after de-/serialization with [`from` and `into`](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html#from).
- I made a crate to make this kind of definition easier to read, [structstruck](https://lib.rs/crates/structstruck), but it still requires defining a lot of structs

You can of course define [custom serializers](https://serde.rs/impl-serialize.html), but that will likely end up being more work than defining the rust structs.